# How do I add a border and shadow to a picture with CSS?

Tags: css, border, shadow

Obviously I have no idea what I am doing and need lots of help. As I said in the title I want to add a border and a shadow to the picture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Instructions: Replicate the same styling seen in the kitten image below. -->

<html>
<head>
<title>Style an Image Quiz</title>
<style>
.kitten-Image{
/*border: medium dashed #fa8072*/
}
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 64px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 64px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 64px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src=https://www.aspca.org/sites/default/files/blog_foster-myth_062718_main.jpg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't add your class to your image

Answer (score 0):

```css
.kitten-Image{
border: 5px dashed #fa8072;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 64px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
}
  Your imgae needs to have a class. and also you need to uncomment styles.
```

```html
<img class="kitten-Image" src=https://www.aspca.org/sites/default/files/blog_foster-myth_062718_main.jpg>
```